# Python recursive call inside a loop. How does it work?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, recursion, iteration

I came across a loop with a recursive function call inside, where the start range of loop is incremented as follows. The code outputs the following sequence as below. However, I unable to conceptualize why this particular sequence is generated. Can somebody throw some insight into its working. And how feasible is it to convert this recursive function into an iterative function outputting the same sequence. Please help.

**Code:**

```
def foo(step=0):
    for i in range(step, 4):
        print step
        foo(step+1)

foo()
```

**Output:**

> 0 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 0 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 0 1 2
>   3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 0 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3

**Code of similar design to find Anagrams:**

```
def find_anagrams(word, step=0):
    print 'step->', step
    if step == len(word):
        print "".join(word)
    for i in range(step, len(word)):
        print step, i
        word_ = list(word)
        word_[step], word_[i] = word_[i], word_[step]
        find_anagrams(word_, step+1)
```

Comment: The way I conceptualize things like this is by executing the program by hand on paper, writing down the values of the variables.

Comment: Indenting output by call depth will make it little bit easier to understand. For example: http://ideone.com/g0ludx

Comment: Yes exactly! I tried doing that. May be I am missing something. Please shed some light.

Comment: *Hint* `print range(step, 4)` before the for loop.

Comment: @thefourtheye how does the value of step become 2 at the fifth recursive call? Can you please explain.

Comment: @Shankar Change your program like this and you should be able to understand this better. `def foo(step=0, level = 0):
    print "{} {}, {}".format("--" * level, step, range(step, 4))
    for i in range(step, 4):
        foo(step + 1, level + 1)

foo()`

Comment: Hard-coded iterative version: http://ideone.com/cILsb1

Comment: Is this question just out of academic interest or what is the goal behind it? Basically loops and recursion are two tools which achieve the same. Some languages are better at loops and others at recursion (and some languages lack support for one of the two). Seeing a recursion in a loop looks quite strange. It looks to me like hammering a screw or screwing a nail.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I have a function that is used to find anagrams of a word using a similar design. I have added the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let me try:**

From your snippet, in every function call i.e foo(step+1) a structure known as an activation record or
frame is created to store information about the progress of that invocation of the function.
So, When the execution of a function leads to a nested function call, the execution of the former call
is suspended and its activation record stores the place in the source code at which the flow of control
should continue upon return of the nested call.

**Here is the main part:**

When step == 4, which in turns range(4,4) == empty list, that time iteration won't happen so it will return
None. Then it will move to the previous frame, where it was stopped and start a new iteration and recursive function call
until range(4,4).

**NB: Recursive base case is only when step == 4, that time range(4,4) and return None.**

**Every recusion needs a base case other wise it will goto infinite loop.**

So, lets see the recursive trace: I am adding `i` to differentiate the `step` and iterative increment.

```
# 1 def foo(step=0):
# 2    for i in range(step, 4):
# 3        print 'i: %d, step: %d' % (i,step)
# 4        foo(step+1)
# 5 foo()

line 5
line 1  foo with step=0  which is default
line 2  range(0,4)                       Frame: A,   0 is over, next=1
line 3  step = 0            Output: i: 0, step: 0
line 4  calling foo(0 + 1)
line 1  foo with step=1
line 2  range(1,4)                       Frame: B,   1 is over, next=2
line 3  step = 1            Output: i: 1, step: 1
line 4  calling foo(1 + 1)
line 1  foo with step=2
line 2  range(2,4)                       Frame: C,   2 is over, next=3
line 3  step = 2            Output: i: 2, step: 2
line 4  calling foo(2 + 1)
line 1  foo with step=3
line 2  range(3,4)                       Frame: D,   3 is over, next=4
line 3  step = 3,           Output: i: 3, step: 3
line 4  calling foo(3 + 1)
line 1  foo with step=4
line 2  range(4,4)                       Frame: E,
         This is an empty list, so it won't come inside the loop, so return None.
         Come back to previous Frame: D, i=3 was used, now increment to 4. So, again range(4,4)
line 2  range(4,4)          Empty list, from Frame: D, return None
         Come back to previous Frame C, now i=3, step was called with value 2
line 2  range(2,4)
line 3  step = 2            Output: i: 3, step: 2, why step == 2 because the function foo was called with step=2
line 4  calling foo(2 + 1)
line 1  foo with step=3
line 2  range(3,4)
line 3  step = 3,           Output : i: 3, step: 3
line 4  calling foo(3 + 1)
line 1  foo with step=4
line 2  range(4,4)          Empty list again, not going inside the list, return None
line 2  range(2,4)          From Frame: B, step was == 1, because the function foo was called with step=1
line 3  step: 1             Output: i: 2, step: 1,  here i ==2, because this is the second iteration of Frame B.
line 4  calling foo(1 + 1)
line 1  foo with step=2
line 2  range(2,4)
line 3  step: 2            Output: i: 2, step: 2
```

After this it follows the same recursive fashion, until the iterative range is exhuausted i.e range(4,4)

Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your anagram code could be refactored avoiding the recursive loop, by using the stdlib:

```
from itertools import permutations

def anagrams (word):
    anagrams = set ()
    for p in permutations (word):
        anagram = ''.join (p)
        anagrams |= {anagram}
    return anagrams

def isAnagram (word1, word2):
    return sorted (word1) == sorted (word2)
```

Comment: Yes! I understand that. But my question is how does the recursive call inside a loop generate such a sequence. I need some insight into the function call.

Comment: PEP 8: Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations: ... Immediately before the open parenthesis that starts the argument list of a function call ...

Comment: @falsetru is correct, see 3rd item: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves

Comment: @falsetru I think it is hilarious that this section of the PEP is titled "Pet Peeves". Exactely to the grain.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, It seems like you mentioned wrong guy ;

Comment: @falsetru Both of you are talking about exactely the same paragraph, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the for loop.  You are iterating through `range(step, 4)`.  If `step = 0` then you are iterating over `[0,1,2,3]`, if `step = 1` then you are iterating over `[1,2,3]` and so on. 
Each time `foo(step)` is called it iterates over that range - **but the range being iterated over in the current call doesn't change**.  So for the first loop you get an iteration from 0 to 3, the second loop is 1-3, etc.

Why does it print like that? Observe.

```
for i in range(0,4):
    print 0
    for j in range(1,4):
        print 1
        for k in range(2,4):
            print 2
            for h in range(3,4):
                 print 3
```

This will have the same output as your recursive function